# Checking for Internet connection with python

Tags: python, urllib

Is this a good way to check for Internet connection in python? As far as I know I shouldn't use bare exceptions.

```
import urllib.request
import time


def connect():
try:
    urllib.request.urlopen('http://google.com')
    return True
except:
    return False


while True:
    if connect():  # checks if there is Internet connection
        print('Connected to Internet.')
    else:
        print("No Internet.")
        time.sleep(10)
        continue  # Loops to beginning and checks for Internet connection again
    main_function()
```

Comment: I think you're looking for [pythonping](https://pypi.org/project/pythonping/), or even just `subprocess.run(["ping", "8.8.8.8"])`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
import socket
ip = socket.gethostbyname(gethostname)
if ip="127.0.0.1":
    print("Not Connected")
else:
    print("Connected!")
```